# How to assign aggregate value from proc sql to a local SAS?

Tags: sas

I have troubles debugging the folowing `proc sql`:

```
%local datasetCount;
%let datasetCount = 0;

proc sql;
            select count(*)
            from path.dataset_list
            into: &datasetCount.;  * I also tried into: datasetCount;
quit;
```

What is my syntax error? I get the folowing

```
ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: ;, ',', ANSIMISS, CROSS, EXCEPT, FULL,
              GROUP, HAVING, INNER, INTERSECT, JOIN, LEFT, NATURAL, NOMISS, ORDER, OUTER, RIGHT,
              UNION, WHERE.

ERROR 76-322: Syntax error, statement will be ignored.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your order is wrong. The ampersand is only desirable if &datasetcount is the name of a macro variable that contains the name of the variable you want to store into (probably not).

```
proc sql;
select count(1) into :datasetcount from path.dataset_list;
quit;
```